# Using JRadioButton for selecting gender

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I am developing a Java desktop app.I need to implement gender selection (male or female) using `JRadioButton` .I have two `JRadioButttons` .But my problem is that here I can select both `JRadioButtons`.How can i restrict this ?

that is I need to select only one at a time.

here is my code snippet

```
     JRadioButton male=new JRadioButton();
     raillabel.add(male);
     male.setBounds(150,152,25,25);
     JRadioButton female=new JRadioButton();
     raillabel.add(female);
     female.setBounds(260,152,25,25);
```

How can i resolve this issue any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them to a `ButtonGroup`.

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(male);
group.add(female);
```

From the [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) tutorial:

> For each group of radio buttons, you need to create a ButtonGroup instance and add each radio button to it. The ButtonGroup takes care of unselecting the previously selected button when the user selects another button in the group.
>
> You should generally initialize a group of radio buttons so that one is selected. However, the API doesn't enforce this rule — a group of radio buttons can have no initial selection. Once the user has made a selection, exactly one button is selected from then on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add them to a `ButtonGroup`.

Try reading the control "howto":

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

It covers all this and more...